# Only returning first parameter in multiple get parameter request

Tags: http, curl, go

I have the following api curl request:

`curl --request GET http://127.0.0.1/juris?d=11111&a=22222`

Inside my `http handler function` which has the arguments: `w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request` i have the code:

```
defer r.Body.Close()
keys,ok := r.URL.Query()["d"]   
if !ok{
 respondWithError(w,http.StatusBadRequest,"InvalidQuery")
 return
}
dnisQuery := string(keys[0])
akeys,aok := r.URL.Query()["a"]     
if !aok{
 respondWithError(w,http.StatusBadRequest,"InvalidQuery")
 return
}
aniQuery := string(akeys[0])
```

It validates and passes the correct value for the first query parameter `d` but it fails for the second parameter `a` with an `InvalidQuery`

Not sure what im doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you issue

```sh
curl --request GET http://127.0.0.1/juris?d=11111&a=22222
```

the shell will see

```sh
curl --request GET http://127.0.0.1/juris?d=11111 & a=22222
```

and run the first command as a background job, that's why the `a` part was ignored. (It actually resulted in the shell setting the variable `a` to `22222`.) To get it to work, you have to escape your URL:

```sh
curl --request GET 'http://127.0.0.1/juris?d=11111&a=22222'
```